# Ruby on Rails Rake assets: precompile error - Connection Refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I'm attempting to run a legacy Rails App using Rails 3.2.8 with Ruby 1.9.3:551 through RVM. I'm aiming to run it using Apache2 with Passenger as well.

Attempting to connect to the site leads to a Passenger error site. Looking through the logs, the issue seems to be with precompiling my assets. When I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace`, I get the error

> **Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
>
> ...
>
> **Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
>
> **Execute tmp:cache:clear
>
> **Excute assets:precompile:primary
>
> [ddtrace] (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/ddtrace-0.26.0/lib/ddtrace/transport/http/clinet.rb:46:in 'rescue in send_request' Internal error during HTTP transport request. Cause: Connection refused - connect(2) Location: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in 'initialize'
>
> ...

What could be causing this issue? I can't seem to find anything about it in ddtrace documentation.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 is effectively dead. Does this code base work with 2.3 or 2.4? Replicating this is not going to be easy because getting versions of Ruby that old running on a modern OS is not really practical. Try and update any and all dependencies you can.

Comment: @tadman Unfortunately it doesn't work on 2.3+. I'll see if I can change the rails version or dependencies to one that works. Thanks.

Comment: You may need to adjust a bunch of the dependency versions to get it to run on 2.3. The alternative is to spin up a VM of a much older OS in order to have a working Ruby 1.9.3, something that [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) can help with.

Comment: Are you able to run the app without Passenger? Can you precompile assets on your machine? Actually, Passenger and the Asset Pipeline are not related. Please clarify which command you run before you see the error above.

Comment: @claasz I cannot precompile the assets on my machine. I am able to run the app with `rails s`. The error above is from the `bundle exec ...` command in the post. Didn't think Passenger was related, but figured I'd mention it just in case.